# Intercept Paste Event of JQTE

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, text-editor, jqte

I am trying to bind an on paste event to my jquery text editor so I can paste as plain text. I have added the second line to my `jquery-te-1.4.0.js`.

```
editor.attr("contenteditable","true").html(thisElementVal);
editor.attr("onPaste","$(this).bind('paste', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'); console.log(text) });").html(thisElementVal);
```

For some reason the output gives,

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined`

Can anybody help me out? Thanks.+

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');` made it work.